# k8s function ParseToLabelSelector with golang but it seems not support '!=' not Equals?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

this is my go file test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/selection"
)
    str := "tier != frontend"
    //fmt.Println(str)
    labelSelector, err := v1.ParseToLabelSelector(str)
    fmt.Println(labelSelector)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("", err)
    }
    selector, err := v1.LabelSelectorAsSelector(labelSelector)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("", err)
    }
    //selector.Matches()
    req, table := selector.Requirements() //key value + operator
    //fmt.Println(req[0].Key(), req[0].Operator(), req[0].Values().List())
    fmt.Println(req, table)
```

run this file, I got:

```
nil
 "!=" is not a valid label selector operator
[] false
```

why NotEqual is not a valid label selector operator?
and I find the ParseToLabelSelector function in k8s code:

```
// ParseToLabelSelector parses a string representing a selector into a LabelSelector object.
// Note: This function should be kept in sync with the parser in pkg/labels/selector.go
func ParseToLabelSelector(selector string) (*LabelSelector, error) {
    reqs, err := labels.ParseToRequirements(selector)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("couldn't parse the selector string \"%s\": %v", selector, err)
    }

    labelSelector := &LabelSelector{
        MatchLabels:      map[string]string{},
        MatchExpressions: []LabelSelectorRequirement{},
    }
    for _, req := range reqs {
        var op LabelSelectorOperator
        switch req.Operator() {
        case selection.Equals, selection.DoubleEquals:
            vals := req.Values()
            if vals.Len() != 1 {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("equals operator must have exactly one value")
            }
            val, ok := vals.PopAny()
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("equals operator has exactly one value but it cannot be retrieved")
            }
            labelSelector.MatchLabels[req.Key()] = val
            continue
        **case selection.In:
            op = LabelSelectorOpIn
        case selection.NotIn:
            op = LabelSelectorOpNotIn
        case selection.Exists:
            op = LabelSelectorOpExists
        case selection.DoesNotExist:
            op = LabelSelectorOpDoesNotExist
        case selection.GreaterThan, selection.LessThan:**
            // Adding a separate case for these operators to indicate that this is deliberate
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%q isn't supported in label selectors", req.Operator())
        default:
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%q is not a valid label selector operator", req.Operator())
        }
        labelSelector.MatchExpressions = append(labelSelector.MatchExpressions, LabelSelectorRequirement{
            Key:      req.Key(),
            Operator: op,
            Values:   req.Values().List(),
        })
    }
    return labelSelector, nil
}
```

here the **switch case didn't contain the "selection.NotEquals"**?
which is not in consonance with [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

I want to use k8s's labelSelector function in my code, how can I fix the problem?

I used the latest k8s golang package :k8s.io/apimachinery v0.24.3

Comment: may be you can uses "not in"?

Comment: yes, as you say if i want to implement "!=", I can use not in. but when "!=" appears in the string, the ParseToLabelSelector(str) will throw an error. Which means that i have to do some  extra things in code before the ParseToLabelSelector(str) to take the "!=" out.